# Не удалаяется файл БД при удалении приложения (Android)

Tags: java, android

Работаю с готовой БД. При запуске приложения копирую из `Assets` в каталог БД приложения по пути:

```
String fileName = fContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getAbsolutePath();
```

В процессе работы всё нормально. При удалении приложения файл БД остаётся в системе.

Проверяю так:

```
String fileName = fContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getAbsolutePath();
File f = new File(fileName);
if(f.exist){
    // Todo
}
```

Как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: "копирую куда положено" - это откуда, куда и как? Приведенная строка кода не дает ясности. Как вы узнаете, что файл БД не удалился? Если файл БД копируется во внутреннюю память в песочницу приложения, то после удаления приложения, разве для проверки, что не удалилось вам нужно иметь рут на устройстве?

Comment: Вы удаляете приложение и заново его устанавливаете, чтобы проверить наличие файла БД? Иначе как после удаления приложения проверять файл на наличие, не запуская приложение? Вообще, возможно, что на устройстве включен автобэкап данных, а оно по умолчанию включено, тогда при удалении и установки приложения, до его запуска данные восстанавливаются из GoogleDrive, включая БД. возможно поможет https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35915039/database-wont-remove-when-uninstall-the-android-application

Comment: @VasilBaymurzin, спасибо! Помогло. Оформите пожалуйста Ваш комментарий как ответ, чтобы я мог добавить Вам репутацию.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Начиная с Android 6 добавлена функция автоматического резервного копирования и восстановления данных приложений. В настройках ОС эта возможность включена по-умолчанию. Для приложений механизм резервного копирования и восстановления включена в манифесте также по-умолчанию. При удалении и последующей установки приложения данные приложения восстанавливаются до запуска приложения.

Ответ в английской версии https://stackoverflow.com/a/41355502

Более подробно по автоматическому резервному копированию и восстановлению по ссылке https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup.html.